# Integrate Bootstrap framework to ionic framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

I'm trying to develop one application's prototype in Ionic framework so pursuing I'm using Ionic framework's Style-sheet and JS but i want to integrate bootstrap's Stylesheets and its JS files in to Ionic framework so it's possible or not if it possible to so please give some hint.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. But I don't see any reason why you need Bootstrap when you have Ionic.

Ionic provides almost all UI elements that styles according to platform and also a very good base css to extend with.

But for some reason if you still want to do it, I would encourage you to use angular-ui instead of the plain vanilla bootstrap that depends on jQuery.

Comment: yes i know ionic provide almost UI but I have already developed prototype using bootstrap and angular but dose not use ionic ...so how to use please give any solution.....